# If $f$ is unif. continuous, then exists $\epsilon>0$ such that every continuous $g$ satisfying $d(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon$ is also uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove or disprove: if $f:M\rightarrow N$ is uniformly continuous, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that every continuous function $g:M\rightarrow N$ satisfying $d(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon $ for every $x\in M$ is also uniformly continuous.

My intuition says that this statement is false, because the hyphotesis of $f$ being uniformly continuous is just to vague to obtain such an $\epsilon$. But i could not come up with a good counter-example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample on $\mathbb{R}$: let $f(x):= 0$ and $g_{\epsilon}(x):= \frac{\epsilon}{2}\sin(x^2)$. We have that $\|f-g_{\epsilon}\|_{\infty} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$, but $g_{\epsilon}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f=0$ and $\epsilon > 0 $.

Let $h$ be a bounded and continuous on $\Bbb R$ (but not uniformly on $\Bbb R$).

define $g= \epsilon \frac{h}{M}$ where $M > 0 $ is a bound for $|h|$.